# Python threading issue: threads blocking each other

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm trying to implement a simple threadpool in python.

I start a few threads with the following code:

```
 threads = []
        for i in range(10):
            t = threading.Thread(target=self.workerFuncSpinner(
            taskOnDeckQueue, taskCompletionQueue, taskErrorQueue, i))
            t.setDaemon(True)
            threads.append(t)
            t.start()

        for thread in threads:
            thread.join()
```

At this point, the worker thread only prints when it starts and exits and time.sleeps between. The problem is, instead of getting output like:

```
#All output at the same time

thread 1 starting
thread 2 starting
thread n starting

# 5 seconds pass

thread 1 exiting
thread 2 exiting
thread n exiting

I get:
thread 1 starting
# 5 seconds pass
thread 1 exiting
thread 2 starting
# 5 seconds pass
thread 2 exiting
thread n starting
# 5 seconds pass
thread n exiting
```

And when I do a threading.current_thread(), they all report they are mainthread.

It's like there not even threads, but running in the main thread context.

Help?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `workerFuncSpinner` in the main thread when creating the `Thread` object. Use a reference to the method instead:

```
t=threading.Thread(target=self.workerFuncSpinner, 
    args=(taskOnDeckQueue, taskCompletionQueue, taskErrorQueue, i))
```

Your original code:

```
t = threading.Thread(target=self.workerFuncSpinner(
    taskOnDeckQueue, taskCompletionQueue, taskErrorQueue, i))
t.start()
```

could be rewritten as

```
# call the method in the main thread
spinner = self.workerFuncSpinner(
    taskOnDeckQueue, taskCompletionQueue, taskErrorQueue, i)

# create a thread that will call whatever `self.workerFuncSpinner` returned, 
# with no arguments
t = threading.Thread(target=spinner)

# run whatever workerFuncSpinner returned in background thread
t.start()
```

You were calling the method serially in the main thread and nothing in the created threads.

Comment: This was it. I don't quite understand why the one arg version assumes main thread context, but thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect workerFuncSpinner may be your problem.  I would verify that it is not actually running the task, but returning a callable object for the thread to run.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread